# Prevent click/pop from transient when bluetooth receiver disconnects?

Tags: amplifier, audio, bluetooth, music

I have a Logitech bluetooth receiver connected to my hifi to allow kids etc to play  music from iPhones/ipads.

However, it seems that the receiver itself has a sleep mode when no signal is being sent, and this sends a pop/click which sounds a bit like plugging a jack while still connected (but nowhere near as bad).

Is there any cheap/simple way of filtering this to prevent the noise and/or damage to the speakers?

Comment: Low filter capacitors, or notch filters, or parametric equalizer?  All of which will kill the performance of your low-end...

Comment: Or a receiver that doesn't go into sleep mode?

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of as I suspected. The annoying thing is that none of the reviews of this device mention the issue, so I'm slightly nervous about splashing out on another in case it does the same. Will have to just bite the bullet.

Comment: It might help if you can find a unit that is not meant to be portable and is not battery operated...

Comment: This isn't portable, but it isn't particularly high quality. In case anyone else wants to avoid it, it's this: https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/bluetooth-audio-adapter